# How to stop ubuntu from prompting for confirmation for remote desktop

Tags: permissions, remote-desktop, 22.04, remote, teamviewer

I was trying to setup a remote desktop solution for an Ubuntu virtual machine running version 22.04 LTS, installed on a Mac Mini that I now use as a home server. However, after I installed TeamViewer host and granted easy access, Ubuntu is still prompting for permission each time I try to connect.

The prompt is titled "Remote Desktop" and says "Select monitor to share with the requesting application" with a toggle to "Allow remote interaction."

Does anyone know how to suppress this prompt?

[image: The Prompt In Question]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you need to switch to X11 rather than Wayland for graphics. See [this article](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/01/ubuntu-21-04-will-use-wayland-by-default).

I've just switch back to X11 and logged in without a problem.

Answer (score 6):

In order to switch to X11:

1. Edit the gdm config:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
   ```
2. Uncomment

   ```
   "WaylandEnable=false"
   ```

and `reboot`.